# Custom js of my module not loading in pub/static Magento2

Tags: magento-2.1, requirejs

I have a custom `myjs.js` file in my module. I have placed the `myjs.js` in `Vendor/module/view/web/js/myjs.js`, my `requirejs-config` is in `Vendor/module/view/frontend`

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'myjs': "vendor_module/js/myjs"
        }
    },

};
```

My js is not loading in `pub/static/frontend`. I want to create `pub/static/frontend/theme/en_US/vendor_module/js/myjs.js` on `static -content:deploy`.

Any suggestion on how can I load?

Comment: Try to deploy again after removing pub/static and var/ folders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your **Custom JS** file in the following directory

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/myjs.js

And your **require-config.js** file is in directory

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/require-config.js

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            myjs: 'Vendor_Module/js/myjs'
        }
    }
};
```

Please use the correct Naming convention as Magento follows.

After this regenerate the static files and flush the cache.

> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
>
> php bin/magento cache:flush

Answer (score 0):

> app/code/vendor/module/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

```
 var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            myjs: 'vendor_module/js/myjs'
        }
    }
 };
```

after use this command:

`php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

`php bin/magento cache:clean`

Comment: It is in the same folder

Comment: It is in the same folder what?

Comment: my requirejs-config.js was in app/code/vendor/module/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js, that was not the problem. But the problem was with web folder. Anyways thank you for responding :)

Comment: I have same problem, in custom module js is not loading from pub/static even js files are available in pub/static